# Source a file within a function takes function parameters

Tags: bash, shell

I have one shell script that sources a second one within the context of a function taking parameters:

```
#!/bin/bash
# bar.sh

function f()
{
   source foo.sh
   echo "Do something else with $1, after foo.sh is sourced."
}

f bar
```

And:

```
#!/bin/bash
# foo.sh

x=${1:-"default"}
echo $x
```

Execution output is the following:

```
$ ./bar.sh 
bar
Do something else with bar, after foo.sh is sourced.
```

I was expecting to get `default` as first line output instead of `bar`. So it turns out that even though I'm not passing any arguments to `foo.sh`, it is taking $1 from the context of function `f`. I can understand this behavior from reading [`bash` documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins), but what would be the best way to override it?

Comment: What is it that you were (or are) expecting?

Comment: @devnull: edited question. Basically, behavior of `foo.sh` is different on `$1` being provided or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### EDIT: Based on your comment and edited question:

```
#!/bin/bash
# bar.sh

function f()
{
   # save $1
   arg1="$1"
   # unset $1
   shift
   # source your script; prints default
   source ./foo.sh
   # restore $1
   set -- $arg1
   # should print bar
   echo $1
   echo "Do something else with $1, after foo.sh is sourced."
}

f bar
```

Comment: I need to source, since the real `foo.sh` updates the environment.

Comment: Well if foo.sh updates the environment then availability of extra `$1` shouldn't hurt, wouldn't it?

Comment: Great, it worked! Please, edit your answer so to remove the 'don't-source' stuff. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. Taken out unwanted part, glad that it worked out.